# Modify MySQL index count

Tags: mysql, database

I recently deleted 2 test users from my "users" table. Now, my index count is out of sync. If a new user signs up I don't see their information until two new users sign up. I have 301 active user accounts in my database. But the account count shows 303. Is there a way to sync the index count?

Comment: How are you handling your data that you can't see new users due to this?

Comment: I guess your index count is ok. you just want your next id to be 302? I am pretty sure if you run `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM yourtable` you correctly get 301 as result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ALTER TABLE `users` AUTO_INCREMENT = 302
```

Comment: This probably won't help them if they delete user 5 of 302.

Comment: Right, but I think he had add 2 test users to the end of the table then delete them, Any way he must describe his problem in more details @Uueerdo

Comment: @Uueerdo correct! I added 2 test users, then deleted them. If I use ALTER TABLE `users` AUTO_INCREMENT = 302 will the count re-sync?

Comment: @Unohoo the next insert will use the number specified, and consecutive ones will continue on from there, but there is no real "syncing". If your logic is reliant on there being no gaps, then the table will become "high maintenance" should you ever remove a user from anywhere but the end.

Comment: @Uueerdo, I should have deactivated the account instead of deleting it. I was told to start over with a fresh database. Because the user table is joined with other tables but I didn't want to lose the users that signed up aleady. Thanks everyone for your help with this issue. And responding so fast, I appreciate it.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!